# Flask python Script runs before values are given

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple Flask python script where I want to via a form add 2 image paths, send those paths to python do stuff and send back a string. The problem I have is that the script runs before the form is filled out and the button is pressed. How to I make the script wait and only run on the press of the submit button?

Code for reference

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    PATH_REFERENCE = request.form.get("referencePhoto")
    PATH_TEST = request.form.get("testPhoto")
    testImage = cv2.imread(PATH_TEST)
    reference = setupReference(PATH_REFERENCE)
    face_locations, face_encodings = getFaceEmbeddingsFromImage(testImage, convertToRGB=True)
    for location, face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):
        distances = face_recognition.face_distance(reference[0], face_encoding)
        if distances <= 0.6:
            result = 'Match!'
        else:
            result = 'Not Match!'
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', result=result)
```

The error is that The script cant do stuff with a NoneObject. Which makes sense condisering the form hasnt sent the paths needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only do the form logic on a Post- on a get, just serve the form.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    result = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
      PATH_REFERENCE = request.form.get("referencePhoto")
      PATH_TEST = request.form.get("testPhoto")
      testImage = cv2.imread(PATH_TEST)
      reference = setupReference(PATH_REFERENCE)
      face_locations, face_encodings = getFaceEmbeddingsFromImage(testImage, convertToRGB=True)
      for location, face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):
          distances = face_recognition.face_distance(reference[0], face_encoding)
          if distances <= 0.6:
              result = 'Match!'
          else:
              result = 'Not Match!'
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', result=result)
```